# Recenter the scrollview content Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, scrollview, frame

I'm trying to recenter the scrollview view and move the frame, when the user current location goes to the out of the screen frame. Currently I have a PDF and I'm showing the user's current location, I am calculating the frame and scrollview zoomScale to showing the current location on PDF View.  I achieve this functionality already. It's working perfectly and I am already drawing the path with the same logic  when the user moves, but I'm stuck at the last point when the user moves and goes out of the screen means hide from the mobile screen then we need to recenter the current location.

**First Code:-**

**Code:-**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.initPdfView()
    self.initCurrentLocation()
}

func initPdfView() {
    do {
        let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory, FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask, true)
        if let path = paths.first {
            let fileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: path).appendingPathComponent("MapBox")
            let document = try PDFDocument.init(at: fileURL)
            pdfController?.page = try document.page(0)
            pdfController?.scrollDelegates = self
            pdfController?.scrollView.layoutSubviews()
        }
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
   
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let visibleRect = CGRect.init(x: sender.contentOffset.x, y: sender.contentOffset.y, width: sender.contentSize.width*sender.zoomScale, height: sender.contentSize.height*sender.zoomScale)
    self.visibleScrollViewRect = visibleRect
    self.zooomLevel = sender.zoomScale
}

func initCurrentLocation() {
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    
    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    guard let locValue: CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location?.coordinate else { return }
    self.currentLocation = locValue
}
```

**ScreenShot:-**

In **first Screenshot**, I'm showing the user's current location.

[First Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqs4E.png)

In **second Screenshot**, I'm drawing the path with the help of user's current location.

[Second Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mK09w.png)

In **third Screenshot**, When user moves and goes out of the screen means hide from the mobile screen.

[Third Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vP5he.png)

**Second Code:-**

```
func initMapDataUserView() {
    guard let mapInfoJson = decodeMapInfo(with: "MapBoxUrl") else {
        return
    }
    
let position = CGPoint.init(x: mapInfoJson.rasterXYsize.first!, y: mapInfoJson.rasterXYsize.last!)
let pointerVal: UnsafePointer<Int8>? = NSString(string: mapInfoJson.projection).utf8String
let decoder = GeoDecode()
    decoder.fetchPdfCoordinateBounds(with: position, projection: pointerVal, initialTransform: mapInfoJson.geotransform) { coordinate, error in
        if let error = error {
            debugPrint(error)
        } else {
            guard let coordinate = coordinate else {
                return
            }
            self.coordinatesUserCurrentLocation = coordinate
            self.initCurrentLocation()
        }
      }
   }

  func initPdfView() {
    do {
        let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory, FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask, true)
        if let path = paths.first {
            let fileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: path).appendingPathComponent("MapBoxUrl")
            let document = try PDFDocument.init(at: fileURL)
            viewPDFController?.page = try document.page(0)
            viewPDFController?.scrollDelegates = self
            viewPDFController?.scrollView.layoutSubviews()
        }
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}


func decodeMapInfo(with value: String) -> MapInfoJson? {
    do {
        guard let valueData = value.data(using: .utf8) else {
            return nil
        }
        let decodedResult = try JSONDecoder().decode(MapInfoJson.self, from: valueData)
        return decodedResult
    } catch {
        print("error: ", error)
    }
    return nil
}

extension MapPreviewViewController: scrollViewActions {

func scrollViewScroll(_ sender: UIScrollView) {
    let visibleRect = CGRect.init(x: sender.contentOffset.x, y: sender.contentOffset.y, width: sender.contentSize.width*sender.zoomScale, height: sender.contentSize.height*sender.zoomScale)
    self.visibleScrollViewRectUserScreen = visibleRect
    self.zooomLevelScrollView = sender.zoomScale
    if coordinatesUserCurrentLocation != nil {
        updateMarkerVisiblityOnPdfView()
      }
   }
}


extension MapPreviewViewController: CLLocationManagerDelegate {

func initCurrentLocation() {
    locationManagerUserTest.delegate = self
    locationManagerUserTest.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManagerUserTest.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    
    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
        locationManagerUserTest.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManagerUserTest.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    guard let locValue: CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location?.coordinate else { return }
    self.currentLocationUser = locValue
    updateMarkerVisiblityOnPdfView()
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
    
}

func updateMarkerVisiblityOnPdfView() {
    guard let locValue: CLLocationCoordinate2D = self.currentLocationUser else { return }
    guard let coordinates = coordinatesUserCurrentLocation else { return }
    
    let yFactor = (locValue.longitude - coordinates.minY) / (coordinates.maxY - coordinates.minY)
    let xFactor = (coordinates.maxX - locValue.latitude) / (coordinates.maxX - coordinates.minX)
    
    var positionX: Double = 0.0
    var positionY: Double = 0.0
    
    positionX = (yFactor*Double(visibleScrollViewRectUserScreen!.size.width))/Double(self.zooomLevelScrollView!)
    positionY = (xFactor*Double(visibleScrollViewRectUserScreen!.size.height))/Double(self.zooomLevelScrollView!)
    
    if visibleScrollViewRectUserScreen!.size.width < 1.0 {
        positionX = (yFactor*Double(18))*Double(self.zooomLevelScrollView!)
        positionY = (xFactor*Double(18))*Double(self.zooomLevelScrollView!)
    }
    
    var indexOfExistingImageView: Int?
    
    for index in 0..<viewPDFController!.scrollView.subviews.count {
        if let imageview = viewPDFController!.scrollView.subviews[index] as? UIImageView {
            if imageview.image == currentmarkerImagView.image {
                indexOfExistingImageView = index
            }
        }
    }
    
    self.currentmarkerImagView.center = .init(x: positionX, y: positionY)
    self.viewPDFController!.scrollView.addSubview(currentmarkerImagView)
    self.viewPDFController!.scrollView.bringSubviewToFront(currentmarkerImagView)
    
   }
 }


public protocol scrollViewActions {
func scrollViewScroll(_ sender: UIScrollView)
}

public class PdfViewViewController: UIViewController {
public var scrollView: UIScrollView!
public var overlayView: UIView!
public var contentView: UIView!
public var scrollDelegates: scrollViewActions?

public override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
     
    scrollView.delegate = self
    scrollView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
     }
  }

  extension PdfViewViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate {
 public func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    scrollDelegates?.scrollViewScroll(scrollView)
}

public func scrollViewDidZoom(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    scrollDelegates?.scrollViewScroll(scrollView)
}

public func scrollViewDidEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {
    scrollDelegates?.scrollViewScroll(scrollView)
}

public func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
}

public func scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
}

public func scrollViewDidEndZooming(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, with view: UIView?, atScale scale: CGFloat) {
    }
}
```

Updated ScreenShot:

In **first Screenshot**, I'm showing the user's current location.

[First Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TU3cu.png)

In **second Screenshot**, When user moves and goes out of the screen means hide from the mobile screen.

[Second Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6KkpN.png)

**Question:** Can someone please explain to me how to recenter the current location or move the scrollview frame when user moves and goes out of the screen.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked at [scrollRectToVisible](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/1619439-scrollrecttovisible)

Comment: @DonMag Yes, I have tried but it's not working, I don't know it's correctly calculated or not at my side. So Could you please help me with this.

Comment: What's calling `scrollViewScroll(...)`? What is `addMakerOnPdfViewMarker()` doing? Best if you can put together a [mre] so we can see these details and offer accurate help.

Comment: ok Sure, @DonMag

Comment: @DonMag, Please check the Second Code and updated Screen shot.

Comment: It would help if you put together a [mre] - but... do you want the "car" to stay centered in the scroll view, with the map scrolling behind it? Or, do you want the car to move until it goes outside the frame of the scroll view, and only then scroll the map, keeping the car visible at the current edge?

Comment: @DonMag, You can use the above code and add any pdf file for example. And No I want when car goes outside the frame of the view, then automatically come back to Center. we need to recenter the car location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I found solution to check and set pdf scrollview Center.**

`Code:-`

```
 func getCurrentLocMakerOutSideFrameOrNot() {
    var visibleRect = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0)
    visibleRect.origin = scrollView.contentOffset
    visibleRect.size = scrollView.bounds.size
     
    if !visibleRect.intersects(currentmarkerImagView.frame) {
        print("Outer View")
        guard let locValue: CLLocationCoordinate2D = self.currentLocation else { return }
        guard let coordinates = coordinates else { return }
        
        let yFactor = (locValue.longitude - coordinates.minY) / (coordinates.maxY - coordinates.minY)
        let xFactor = (coordinates.maxX - locValue.latitude) / (coordinates.maxX - coordinates.minX)
        
        var positionX: Double = 0.0
        var positionY: Double = 0.0
        
        positionX = (yFactor*Double(visibleScrollViewRectView!.size.width))/Double(self.zooomLevelView!)
        positionY = (xFactor*Double(visibleScrollViewRectView!.size.height))/Double(self.zooomLevelView!)
        
        if visibleScrollViewRectView!.size.width < 1.0 {
            positionX = (yFactor*Double(18))*Double(self.zooomLevelView!)
            positionY = (xFactor*Double(18))*Double(self.zooomLevelView!)
        }

        let centerPoint = CGPoint(x: positionX-190, y: positionY-295)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.5, animations: {
              scrollView.setContentOffset(centerPoint, animated: false)
              scrollView.setZoomScale(self.pdfController!.scrollView.zoomScale/2, animated: false)
         })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, obviously, we can't create a new project, paste in the code you posted, and run it.

So... hopefully this will help.

A scroll view's `.bounds` is the ***visible rectangle*** of its `.contentSize`.

So, if we take this example:

- create a 400x600 "mapView" (as the `viewForZooming`)
- add a 30x30 "marker" subview at `origin: x: 240, y: 400`
- use a scrollview (yellow background) with a 200 x 300 frame
- constrain all 4 sides of the mapView to the scrollview's `.contentLayoutGuide`

It will look like this to begin with at 1.0 zoom (everything outside the scrollview's frame will be hidden, of course):

[image]

the scrollview will have:

```
ContentSize: (400.0, 600.0)
Bounds:      (0.0, 0.0, 200.0, 300.0)
```

If we scroll all the way to the bottom right corner, it will look like this:

[image]

with:

```
ContentSize: (400.0, 600.0)
Bounds:      (200.0, 300.0, 200.0, 300.0)
```

If we zoom in to 2.0 zoom scale, we get:

```
ContentSize: (800.0, 1200.0)
Bounds:      (0.0, 0.0, 200.0, 300.0)

ContentSize: (800.0, 1200.0)
Bounds:      (600.0, 900.0, 200.0, 300.0)
```

If we zoom in to 3.0 zoom scale, we get:

```
ContentSize: (1200.0, 1800.0)
Bounds:      (0.0, 0.0, 200.0, 300.0)

ContentSize: (1200.0, 1800.0)
Bounds:      (1000.0, 1500.0, 200.0, 300.0)
```

and if we zoom **out** to 0.5 zoom scale:

```
ContentSize: (200.0, 300.0)
Bounds:      (0.0, 0.0, 200.0, 300.0)
```

The first task is to find out if the "marker" is visible... if it is, we don't need to do anything. If it's *not* visible (scrolled outside the frame), we want to center it.

So, if we've scrolled like this:

[image]

we can say:

```
let r = marker.frame
let isInside = scrollView.bounds.contains(r)
```

in this case, `isInside` will be `true`.

But, if the marker is *outside* the frame like this:

[image]

we want to define a `CGRect` that is the same width and height as the scrollview's bounds, centered on the center of the marker:

[image]

and we can call:

```
scrollView.scrollRectToVisible(r, animated: true)
```

Of course, if our marker view is close to an edge, like this:

[image]

that's as close to the center as its going to get.

That's not *quite* enough though...

The marker view's frame will always be its own frame - it get scaled when the scroll view's zoom scale changes. So, we need to account for that:

```
let r = marker.frame.applying(CGAffineTransform(scaleX: self.scrollView.zoomScale, y: self.scrollView.zoomScale))
let isInside = scrollView.bounds.contains(r)
```

Here's a complete example demo... we create the "map view" at twice the size of the scroll view, minZoom: 0.5, maxZoom: 3.0, arrange a pattern of "markers" and use two buttons to "Highlight and Center if Needed":

[image] [image]

Note: ***Sample Code Only*** - not intended to be "production ready":

```
class CenterInScrollVC: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {
    
    let scrollView: UIScrollView = {
        let v = UIScrollView()
        return v
    }()
    
    // can be any type of view
    //  using a "Dashed Outline" so we can see its edges
    let mapView: DashView = {
        let v = DashView()
        v.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.9, alpha: 0.5)
        v.color = .blue
        v.style = .border
        return v
    }()

    var mapMarkers: [UIView] = []
    var markerIndex: Int = 0
    
    // let's make the markers 40x40
    let markerSize: CGFloat = 40.0
    
    // percentage of one-half of marker that must be visible to NOT screll to center
    //  1.0 == entire marker must be visible
    //  0.5 == up to 1/4 of marker may be out of view
    //  <= 0.0 == only check that the Center of the marker is in view
    //  can be set to > 1.0 to require entire marker Plus some "padding"
    let pctVisible: CGFloat = 1.0
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        
        // a button to center the current marker (if needed)
        let btnA: UIButton = {
            let v = UIButton()
            v.backgroundColor = .systemRed
            v.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
            v.setTitleColor(.lightGray, for: .highlighted)
            v.setTitle("Center Current if Needed", for: [])
            v.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnATap(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
            return v
        }()
        
        // a button to select the next marker, center if needed
        let btnB: UIButton = {
            let v = UIButton()
            v.backgroundColor = .systemRed
            v.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
            v.setTitleColor(.lightGray, for: .highlighted)
            v.setTitle("Go To Marker - 2", for: [])
            v.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnBTap(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
            return v
        }()
        
        // add a view with a "+" marker to show the center of the scroll view
        let centerView: DashView = {
            let v = DashView()
            v.backgroundColor = .clear
            v.color = UIColor(red: 0.95, green: 0.2, blue: 1.0, alpha: 0.5)
            v.style = .centerMarker
            v.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
            return v
        }()
        
        [btnA, btnB, mapView, scrollView, centerView].forEach { v in
            v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        }
        
        [btnA, btnB, scrollView, centerView].forEach { v in
            view.addSubview(v)
        }

        scrollView.addSubview(mapView)
        
        let safeG = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        let contentG = scrollView.contentLayoutGuide
        let frameG = scrollView.frameLayoutGuide
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            // buttons at the top
            btnA.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeG.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            btnA.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeG.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.7),
            btnA.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeG.centerXAnchor),
            
            btnB.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: btnA.bottomAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            btnB.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: btnA.widthAnchor),
            btnB.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeG.centerXAnchor),
            
            // let's inset the scroll view to make it easier to distinguish
            scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: btnB.bottomAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeG.leadingAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeG.trailingAnchor, constant: -40.0),
            scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeG.bottomAnchor, constant: -40.0),
            
            // overlay "center lines" view
            centerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor),
            centerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor),
            centerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor),
            centerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor),

            // mapView Top/Leading/Trailing/Bottom to scroll view's CONTENT GUIDE
            mapView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentG.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            mapView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentG.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            mapView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentG.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            mapView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentG.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            
            // let's make the mapView twice as wide and tall as the scroll view
            mapView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: frameG.widthAnchor, multiplier: 2.0),
            mapView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: frameG.heightAnchor, multiplier: 2.0),
            
        ])
        
        // some example locations for the Markers
        let pcts: [[CGFloat]] = [
            
            [0.50, 0.50],
            
            [0.25, 0.50],
            [0.50, 0.25],
            [0.75, 0.50],
            [0.50, 0.75],

            [0.10, 0.15],
            [0.90, 0.15],
            [0.90, 0.85],
            [0.10, 0.85],
            
        ]
        for (i, p) in pcts.enumerated() {
            let v = UILabel()
            v.text = "\(i + 1)"
            v.textAlignment = .center
            v.textColor = .yellow
            v.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
            v.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 15.0, weight: .bold)
            v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            mapMarkers.append(v)
            mapView.addSubview(v)
            v.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: markerSize).isActive = true
            v.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: v.widthAnchor).isActive = true
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: v, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: mapView, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: p[0], constant: 0.0).isActive = true
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: v, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: mapView, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: p[1], constant: 0.0).isActive = true
        }
        
        scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 0.5
        scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 3.0
        scrollView.delegate = self
        
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        
        // let's start with the scroll view zoomed out
        scrollView.zoomScale = scrollView.minimumZoomScale
        
        // highlight and center (if needed) the 1st marker
        markerIndex = 0
        let marker = mapMarkers[markerIndex % mapMarkers.count]
        highlightMarkerAndCenterIfNeeded(marker, animated: true)
    }

    @objc func btnATap(_ sender: Any?) {
        // to easily test "center if not visible" without changing the "current marker"
        let marker = mapMarkers[markerIndex % mapMarkers.count]
        highlightMarkerAndCenterIfNeeded(marker, animated: true)
    }
    
    @objc func btnBTap(_ sender: Any?) {
        // increment index to the next marker
        markerIndex += 1
        let marker = mapMarkers[markerIndex % mapMarkers.count]
        // center if needed
        highlightMarkerAndCenterIfNeeded(marker, animated: true)
        // update button title
        if let b = sender as? UIButton, let m = mapMarkers[(markerIndex + 1) % mapMarkers.count] as? UILabel, let t = m.text {
            b.setTitle("Go To Marker - \(t)", for: [])
        }
    }
    
    func highlightMarkerAndCenterIfNeeded(_ marker: UIView, animated: Bool) {
        
        // "un-highlight" all markers
        mapMarkers.forEach { v in
            v.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
        }
        // "highlight" the new marker
        marker.backgroundColor = .systemGreen

        // get the marker frame, scaled by zoom scale
        var r = marker.frame.applying(CGAffineTransform(scaleX: self.scrollView.zoomScale, y: self.scrollView.zoomScale))
        
        // inset the rect if we allow less-than-full marker visible
        if pctVisible > 0.0 {
            let iw: CGFloat = (1.0 - pctVisible) * r.width * 0.5
            let ih: CGFloat = (1.0 - pctVisible) * r.height * 0.5
            r = r.insetBy(dx: iw, dy: ih)
        }
        
        var isInside: Bool = true
        
        if pctVisible <= 0.0 {
            // check center point only
            isInside = self.scrollView.bounds.contains(CGPoint(x: r.midX, y: r.midY))
        } else {
            // check the rect
            isInside = self.scrollView.bounds.contains(r)
        }
        
        // if the marker rect (or point) IS inside the scroll view
        //  we don't do anything
        
        // if it's NOT inside the scroll view
        //  center it
        
        if !isInside {
            // create a rect using scroll view's bounds centered on marker's center
            let w: CGFloat = self.scrollView.bounds.width
            let h: CGFloat = self.scrollView.bounds.height
            r = CGRect(x: r.midX, y: r.midY, width: w, height: h).offsetBy(dx: -w * 0.5, dy: -h * 0.5)

            if animated {
                // let's slow down the animation a little
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.75, delay: 0.0, options: [.curveEaseInOut], animations: {
                    self.scrollView.scrollRectToVisible(r, animated: false)
                }, completion: nil)
            } else {
                self.scrollView.scrollRectToVisible(r, animated: false)
            }
        }
        
    }

    func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
        return mapView
    }
    
}
```

---

**Edit** -- as noted in the code comments, any view can be used for `viewForZooming`, but here's the code for the `DashView` I used:

```
class DashView: UIView {
    // border or
    // vertical and horizontal center lines or
    // two lines forming a + in the center
    enum Style: Int {
        case border
        case centerLines
        case centerMarker
    }
    
    public var style: Style = .border {
        didSet {
            setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }

    // solid or dashed
    public var solid: Bool = false
    
    // line color
    public var color: UIColor = .yellow {
        didSet {
            dashLayer.strokeColor = color.cgColor
        }
    }
    
    private let dashLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    private func commonInit() {
        layer.addSublayer(dashLayer)
        dashLayer.strokeColor = color.cgColor
        dashLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        dashLayer.lineWidth = 2
        
    }
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        var bez = UIBezierPath()
        switch style {
        case .border:
            bez = UIBezierPath(rect: bounds)
            dashLayer.lineDashPattern = [10, 10]

        case .centerLines:
            bez.move(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.minY))
            bez.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.maxY))
            bez.move(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.minX, y: bounds.midY))
            bez.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.maxX, y: bounds.midY))
            dashLayer.lineDashPattern = [10, 10]

        case .centerMarker:
            bez.move(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.midY - 40.0))
            bez.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.midY + 40.0))
            bez.move(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.midX - 40.0, y: bounds.midY))
            bez.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.midX + 40.0, y: bounds.midY))
            dashLayer.lineDashPattern = []
        }
        if solid {
            dashLayer.lineDashPattern = []
        }
        dashLayer.path = bez.cgPath
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I will check and update you shortly.

Comment: Could you please add the `DashView` Coding.

Comment: @RsD - sorry, thought I had included it. See the **Edit**

Comment: Thank you. I will check and update you.