# Alternative way to check intersect scrollview subview frame Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, frame, cgrect

Currently i'm following the below code to check the two CGRect Frame intersects.

**Code:-**

```
var visibleRect = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0)
visibleRect.origin =   scrollView.contentOffset
visibleRect.size   =   scrollView.bounds.size

if !visibleRect.intersects(ImagView.frame) { 
     print("Outer View")
}else{
     print("Inner View")     
}
```

This code works When `ImagView` frame goes totally out of visibleRect. But we need when imageview frame origin close to scrollview frame origin. More detail Please check the screen shot.

[image: Second Screenshot]

When the car move out from the screen the above code working perfectly. But we need when car near to close out from the scrollview frame.

**Question:** Can someone please explain to me how to get near to close out?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The answer I gave you to your other question - https://stackoverflow.com/a/71888509/6257435 - does exactly this.

Comment: @DonMag, ok i will check